# Apply a function to a specific row using the index value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following table:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Dataframe with random numbers and with an a,b,c,d,e index
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), index = ['a','b','c','d','e'])

#Now i name the columns the same
df.columns = ['a','b','c','d','e']

#Resulting dataframe:
        a         b         c         d         e
a  2.214229  1.621352  0.083113  0.818191 -0.900224
b -0.612560 -0.028039 -0.392266  0.439679  1.596251
c  1.378928 -0.309353 -0.651817  1.499517  0.515772
d -0.061682  1.141558 -0.811471  0.242874  0.345159
e -0.714760 -0.172082  0.205638  0.220528  1.182013
```

How can i apply a function to the dataframes index? I want to round the numbers for every column where the index is "c".

```
#Numbers to round to 2 decimals: 
       a         b         c         d         e
c  1.378928 -0.309353 -0.651817  1.499517  0.515772
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I think your title is a bit misleading, what you are saying really is you want to apply a function to a specific row using the index value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For label based indexing use `loc`:

```
In [22]:

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), index = ['a','b','c','d','e'])

#Now i name the columns the same
df.columns = ['a','b','c','d','e']
df
Out[22]:
          a         b         c         d         e
a -0.051366  1.856373 -0.224172 -0.005668  0.986908
b -1.121298 -1.018863  2.328420 -0.117501 -0.231463
c  2.241418 -0.838571 -0.551222  0.662890 -1.234716
d  0.275063  0.295788  0.689171  0.227742  0.091928
e  0.269730  0.326156  0.210443 -0.494634 -0.489698
In [23]:

df.loc['c'] = np.round(df.loc['c'],decimals=2)
df
Out[23]:
          a         b         c         d         e
a -0.051366  1.856373 -0.224172 -0.005668  0.986908
b -1.121298 -1.018863  2.328420 -0.117501 -0.231463
c  2.240000 -0.840000 -0.550000  0.660000 -1.230000
d  0.275063  0.295788  0.689171  0.227742  0.091928
e  0.269730  0.326156  0.210443 -0.494634 -0.489698
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But by round i meant that the 2.240000 -0.840000 -0.550000  0.660000 -1.230000 values to be returned as 2.24 -0.84 0.55 0.66 -1.23. How can i do that?

Comment: @Uninvited That's a display issue as the rest of your values in the columns have more decimal places you can't change the display just for that row unless you converted everything to strings which is probably not what you want

Comment: So it works only with assignment? Because if i hard type something like df.loc['c'] = 1.23 it displays it properly with 2 decimals only.

Comment: And how can i do that with str() for representation purposes? I tried something like df.loc['c'].to_string() or df.loc['c'] = str(df.loc['c']) but the results were not the ones i hoped for.

Comment: No you'd have to do it for the entire df so `for col in df: df[col] = df[col],astype(str)` I think should work but I don't see the point as it's just a display issue, the value is correct

Comment: That helps a lot (as type). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To round values of column c:

```
df['c'].round(decimals=2)
```

To round values of row c:

```
df.loc['c'].round(decimals=2)
```